# Subquery in Select Statement in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, subquery

I want to use this subquery in select statement

```
select category from `categories` WHERE id = `products`.`category_id`
```

Here is select statement part of my method

```
$query = $this->select(
   DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT(`order_details`.`product_id`)) as productCount'), 'products.category_id',
   DB::raw('('.DB::select('select category from `categories` WHERE id = `products`.`category_id` ').') AS category ')
);
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select category from `categories` WHERE id = `products`.`category_id` )
```

I hate using direct select statement. Because it is not good if i will change database.

Despite of using direct select statement it is not working. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply update your following statement

```
DB::raw('('.DB::select('select category from `categories` WHERE id = `products`.`category_id` ').') AS category ')
```

into

```
DB::raw('(select category from `categories` WHERE id = `products`.`category_id`) AS category')
```

Over here the error is for unknown column `products.category_id` you need to check are you have `category_id` within your table

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the example below for one of the subquery:

```
$result = static::select('id')
        ->where( 'id', '!=', $currentLevelId)
        ->where('level', '>', DB::raw("(SELECT level FROM " . $this->table . " WHERE id='".$currentLevelId."')") )
        ->orderBy('level')->first();
```

Outcome Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `approval_levels` WHERE `id` != 2 AND `level` > (SELECT LEVEL
 FROM approval_levels WHERE id='2') ORDER BY `level` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Hope it helps!